# Lyx+knitr code externalization with read_chunk('foo.R') fails

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

I am trying to use `read_chunk()` to separate my R code from my Lyx file as explained [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/).

My Lyx setup compiled the `knitr_minimal.pdf` from [`knitr_minimal.lyx`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/master/inst/examples) without any issues.

But then I tried to replace this:

```
<<boring-random>>=
set.seed(1121)
(x=rnorm(20))
mx <- mean(x)
vx <- var(x)
@
```

> The first element of x is \Sexpr{x[1]}. Its mean is \Sexpr{mx}.

with this:

```
<<boring-random, cache=FALSE>>=
read_chunk('minimal.R')
@
```

> The first element of x is \Sexpr{x[1]}. Its mean is \Sexpr{mx}.

The script `minimal.R` is saved in the same directory, and consists of just

```
set.seed(1121)
(x=rnorm(20))
mx <- mean(x)
vx <- var(x)
```

I saved the modified file as `knitr_minimal1.lyx` and compiled it. The file `knitr_minimal1.pdf` compiled alright, but instead of

> The first element of x is 0.145. Its mean is 0.3217.

I see

> The first element of x is Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object ’x’ not found. Its mean is Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object ’mx’ not found.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a label to your code in `minimal.R` corresponding to the chunk label in your LyX document, otherwise `knitr` does not know where to insert the code.

```
## @knitr boring-random
set.seed(1121)
(x=rnorm(20))
mx <- mean(x)
vx <- var(x)
```

If you open the R script in the `knitr` [web page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/), you will see several lines of comments of the form `## @knitr label`. I will update the web page to clarify this. There is an alternative approach to specify the labels, which is documented in `?knitr::read_chunk`.

The second problem of your LyX document is you put `read_chunk()` in the `boring-random` chunk, but you really need to read the code *before* you insert it into a chunk.

```
<<setup>>=
read_chunk('minimal.R')
@
<<boring-random>>=
@
```

Comment: Thank you, Yihui, but this still produces the same error message. Besides adding the label you mention, I also tried `read_chunk("minimal.R", labels = "boring-random", from = 1, to = 5)` and `read_chunk("minimal.R", labels = "boring-random", from = 2, to = 5)` and `read_chunk("minimal.R", labels = "boring-random")` to no avail. And it's good you brought up the [knitr code externalization](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/) page, because that's where it all started. But I'll get to that once I sort out `knitr_minimal1.lyx`.

Comment: @Gabi Okay, just realized another problem there. See the updated answer. Perhaps you did not read the PDF manual (http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/manual/) and jumped too quickly into this feature, so there was misunderstanding.

Comment: Duh. Sorry. This works perfectly, of course. Now on to my original example of code externalization. Turns out I need a few packages before I can run your homework examples: `tikzDevice` and `filehash` are the first two reported missing so far. This, by the way, is a lot easier to figure out while trying to compile pdf from Rnw in Rstudio. The LyX error messages are unhelpful at first, then Lyx just quits unexpectedly with an invitation to report this to Apple. I will report on my progress. Thanks again.

Comment: With these two R packages installed -- `tikzDevice` from R-forge and `filehash` from CRAN -- I could compile both `Stat546-HW4-Xie.Rnw` and `Stat546-HW4-Xie.lyx`. All is well.

Comment: See the LyX/Sweave manual for troubleshooting (Section 4): http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/ The error dialog is not helpful at all.